# Make stickynotes stick to the desktop

Tags: stickynotes

I can only choose to have my note(s) either disappear so I need two clicks to bring them back or have them in my face all the time. Instead I want them to stick to the desktop. Is this possible? I couldn't find the option.

Example: When I press Super + D key I get the desktop without the note on it.

Comment: Updated the question with additional explanation.